# avconv (ffmpeg): correct audio codec

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have an error when tryying to convert video from flash recorder to mp4:

```
ubuntu@media:/data/media/failed$ avconv -i videoStream_1356794393712_805.flv -acodec aac  videoStream_1356794393712_805.mp4
avconv version 0.8.4-4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:51:33 with gcc 4.6.3
[libspeex @ 0x1091500] Missing Speex header, assuming defaults.
[flv @ 0x108d7a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'videoStream_1356794393712_805.flv':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Sat Dec 29 15:20:12
  Duration: 00:00:04.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libspeex, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16
[buffer @ 0x1093a00] w:640 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p
[mpeg4 @ 0x1094ce0] removing common factors from framerate
[aac @ 0x108d120] Too many bits per frame requested
Output #0, mp4, to 'videoStream_1356794393712_805.mp4':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Sat Dec 29 15:20:12
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 200 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (libspeex -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
ubuntu@media:/data/media/failed$
```

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, default ffmpeg/avconv.
How can I solve this problem?

ffprobe log:

```
ubuntu@media:/data/media/failed$ ffprobe videoStream_1356794393712_805.flv
avprobe version 0.8.4-4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:51:33 with gcc 4.6.3
[libspeex @ 0x1c27500] Missing Speex header, assuming defaults.
[flv @ 0x1c237a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'videoStream_1356794393712_805.flv':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Sat Dec 29 15:20:12
  Duration: 00:00:04.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libspeex, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16
[libspeex @ 0x1c27500] Missing Speex header, assuming defaults.
ubuntu@media:/data/media/failed$
```

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). *Maybe* it could be migrated to Ask Ubuntu or Super User...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution.
ffmpeg should be downloaded in binary version (linux x64) from links from official site.

Ubuntu versions have problems with codecs.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
It's required to install these packages: `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53 libavdevice-extra-53 libavfilter-extra-2 libavformat-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51 libpostproc-extra-52 libswscale-extra-2`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in Ubuntu 14.04 by using the libvo_aacenc codec instead of the aac codec. You could change your command to look something like this:

```
avconv -i videoStream_1356794393712_805.flv -c:v mpeg4 -c:a libvo_aacenc  videoStream_1356794393712_805.mp4
```